# Downloadable large remote images using PHP

Tags: php, curl, stream, download

I know there are lots of posts similar to this, but after crawling SO, still not found the answer.

I am looking to write a script that acts as a proxy for downloading large remote images (around  10mb each). So far I am using curl to read in the remote image url and then using headers to force a download. Something like (not the full script):

```
function getRemoteFile($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

header('Content-Type: octet/stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="random.jpg"');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file));
echo $file;
```

This works, but is there a better way as this script may see quite a lot of traffic - maybe 300 concurrent users with 10 requests each?

The images will be served from a server on the same network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10mb` is pretty large with `300 concurrent users with 10 requests`.

You are saying `10 * 300 * 10 = 30,000 MB = 30GB`

I Suggest you use a Job Queue

You can use `Gearman`

```
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("download", "getRemoteFile");
while ($worker->work());
```

You can not use AJAX and to check if the image is downloaded and display it

I would also recommend you look at the following

- [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/)
- [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)
- [dropr](https://github.com/s0enke/dropr/)

Comment: Yes - the usage is an issue. I have just started installing Gearman to give it a whirl. Thanks for a speedy response!